# Optaplanner starting from existing result

Tags: merge, system, optaplanner, heuristics, construct

My team has a plan to apply optaplanner to existing system.

Existing system has its own rule-sets.
it tries own rule-sets one by one and pick the one as best result.

We want to start from its result as heuristics
and start to solve the problem as meta-heuristics.

We have reviewed optaplanner manual especially in repeated planning section.
but we can't find the way.

Is there a way to accept existing system's result?
your cooperation would be highly appreciated

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

For OptaPlanner, it makes no difference where the input solution comes from. Consider the following code:

```
MyPlanningSolution solution = readSolution();
Solver<MyPlanningSolution> solver = SolverFactory.create(...)
     .buildSolver();
solver.solve(solution);
```

Notice how `solution` comes from a custom method, `readSolution()`. Whether that method generates the initial solution randomly, reads it from a file, from a database etc., that does not matter to the solver. It also does not matter if it is initialized or not - construction heuristic, if configured, will just skip the initialized entities.

That means you have absolute freedom in how you create your initial solution and, to the solver, they all look the same.